# Did Tirol annex land (right flank of Val d'Avigna) from Switzerland between 1859 and 1869?

Tags: 19th-century, switzerland, austria-hungary

Map from 1859:
[image]

The river in the middle of Val d'Avigna is described as the border between Switzerland and Austria.

An earlier map from 1853 shows the same border:[image: Map 1853 val d'avigna]

On a map from 1869 the border is different:
[image]

It seems the right flank of the river has been annexed by Tirol from Switzerland, on the oldest map the border follows the river and as such the valley is spit in two, from 1869 on, the border follows the summits and the valley is entierely Austrian.

Modern map of the eara :
http://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=13/46.6649/10.3987

(Notice that since WW1 the land in question is part of Italian South Tirol)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This 1770s map](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Atlas_Tyrolensis-small.jpg) appears to show the border running along the ridge line, as in your 1869 example, suggesting that if there was any change it was relatively short-lived. Given this, I wonder if the 1859 line may simply be a cartographical error...

[image]